# How to prevent user from deleting sheet, but leave all else open

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have developed an Excel Application in which useres can enter custom categories. I let the user call up and hide this data entry worksheet with a button in the custom ribbon.

Now I've realized that the user can accidentally delete these worksheets. How do I disable the delete command for this worksheet while leaving all else open?

I've been searching the web but have come up empty on this.

This is for Excel 2007

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protect them.

`Tools > Protection > Protect Worksheet.`

Add the password and choose what actions your users should do in the sheets.

You can do the same using `VBA` too. Check the following [link](http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/02/03/ribbon-step-by-step-part-3-the-office-menu-and-re-purposing.aspx)

**Updated with a code for sheet level protect**

You may put the following code in the sheet that you need to manage any mischief ;)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="Password", Structure:=True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="Password"
End Sub
```

But you see, when you have a book with 100 sheets and if you want 50 sheets to be protected. 
Then you gotta either save all the sheet indices into a `very hidden sheet`. Usee that list in a module level VBA code to trigger the protect. Because not everytime you will have sheets in asceding order. If sheet indices in an order you can simply iterate them.

Let me know if you like to have workbook level code as well.

Comment: don't protect the sheet ... you must to protect the *Workbook* "for structure" (found in the review tab for 2007/2010)

Comment: @bonCodigo  I have checked what options are available to me in the workbook protection settings and this does not provide me with the option to simply protect the worksheet and leave all else open. For example, it does not give me the option of letting the users enter more rows or delete them in a Datatable.

Comment: @MikeD  The workbook "structure" command is not in Excel 2007. It appears in Excel 2010. That is in fact the one I would have used otherwise!

Comment: @excelnova you can write the VBA with sheet activate event or you can write a VBA to protect the sheets that you need leave everything else open.

Comment: @bonCodigo Maybe I don't understand your answer... could you give me an example? i looked at the link you posted and read Ron de Bruin's article, but that solution would essentially completley take out the option of deleting any worksheet. i need to only prevent one specific worksheet from being deleted. the useres MUST in fact still be able to delete other sheets. tell me if what i wrote is confusing or not precise enough... thanks.

Comment: @bonCodigo Upvoted your answer as it does not deserve a -1. back to 0.

Comment: Well thanks ;) let me post you a tested sample to make sure only x,y,z sheets can't be deleted, rest are open for any action from user.

Comment: This no longer works in Office 365. Even though the _Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells_ check box is ticked, the user can still delete the sheet after it is protected. Hopefully this is a bug and Microsoft will fix it.